# How to set the background color of tab panel with default css class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a tab panel where i have used "ajax__tab_xp" default css class.BUt i want to set the background color with the existing css class.

My code:

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer2" runat="server" Height="258px" Width="100%" ActiveTabIndex="0" TabStripPlacement="Top" CssClass="ajax__tab_xp" useverticalstripplacement="true"  verticalstripwidth="100px">


.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_body {font-family:verdana,tahoma,helvetica;font-size:10pt;border:1px solid #999999;border-top:0;padding:8px;background-color:#ffffff;}
```

I have almost tried every possibilities but it is not working.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: @RononDex with this css class i am unable to set the background color

Comment: background-color: pink;

Comment: @AshleyMedway I have tried this but it does not work with the existing css class

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, post you css code

Comment: @ronnodex used style="background-color:green" inside the control and  .ajax__tab_xp {
        background-color:#f00;
        }

Comment: apply !important to property. like 
'.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_body {font-family:verdana,tahoma,helvetica;font-size:10pt;border:1px solid #999999;border-top:0;padding:8px;background-color:#ffffff !important;} '

Comment: @DeepSharma Thanks,let me try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply !important to property like:

`.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_body {font-family:verdana,tahoma,helvetica;font-size:10pt;border:1px solid #999999;border-top:0;padding:8px;background-color:#ffffff !important;}`